# How to handle long press with ngx-long-press in angular9?

Tags: angular, angular9

I've got an issue with making `longPress` work in angular 9. I've imported the module following https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-long-press and I've got a simple button

```
<button [longPress] (onRelease)="onLongPress()" > </button>
```

and a simple

```
onLongPress(){
    console.log("long press works");
  }
```

in my ts file.
However the console log never shows up. There is no error in the console, just nothing happens, so my question is: should this module be working with Angular 9? 
And if not, what is the best module to handle long press in angular 9?

Comment: have you imported the directive in your module?

Comment: Ok, now I have generated a directive, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add longPress directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, OnInit, 

Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Clipboard } from '@ionic-native/clipboard';
import { Gesture } from 'ionic-angular/gestures/gesture';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var Hammer;

@Directive({
  selector: '[longPress]'
})

export class PressDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() onLongPressEvent = new EventEmitter();
  el: HTMLElement;
  pressGesture: Gesture;

  constructor(el: ElementRef, private clipboard: Clipboard, private plt: Platform) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
    this.onLongPressEvent.emit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.plt.is('ios')) {
      this.pressGesture = new Gesture(this.el);
    } else {
      this.pressGesture = new Gesture(this.el,
        {
          recognizers: [
            [Hammer.Press, { time: 1000 }]
          ]
        });
    }
    this.pressGesture.listen();
    this.pressGesture.on('press', e => {
      this.clipboard.copy(e.target.textContent.trim());
      this.onLongPressEvent.emit();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.pressGesture.destroy();
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added `@Directive({
  selector: '[longPress]'
})` to my code now, do I also need to add other things like `@Output() onLongPressEvent = new EventEmitter();` and things in `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: Ok nevermind, now I understood that I need to generate a directive, is that right?

Comment: @Ecuros Yes, or this example may help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/press-gesture?file=app%2Findicator.ts

Answer (score 0):

Here a standalone directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, inject } from "@angular/core";
import { fromEvent, merge, zip } from "rxjs";
import { filter, map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Directive({
    selector: "[longPress]",
    standalone: true
})
export class LongPressDirective {

    @Input() threshold = 500;

    private readonly elementRef = inject(ElementRef);

    private mouseDown$ = merge(
            fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchstart'),
            fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "mousedown")
        ).pipe(
            map((event) => {
            const ts = Date.now();
            return { event, ts };
        })
    );

    private mouseUp$ = merge(
        fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchend'),
        fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "mouseup")
        ).pipe(
        map((event) => {
        const ts = Date.now();
        return { event, ts };
        })
    );

    @Output() mouseLongPress = zip(this.mouseDown$, this.mouseUp$).pipe(
        filter(([down, up]) => up.ts - down.ts >= 300),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with a standalone directive, using interval. The difference with this solution is that it emits the `onLongPress` when the user hold the button (or any other element) long enough, not having to wait for the `mouseup` or `touchend` event. Instead it cancels the long press when the press is released during hold.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, inject, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, merge, take } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
    standalone: true,
    selector: '[longPress]',
})
export class HoldToCopyDirective {
    @Input() thresholdSeconds = 1;

    @Output() onLongPress: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

    private readonly elementRef = inject(ElementRef);
    private interval: NodeJS.Timer | undefined;

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
    onMouseDown() {
        let val = 0;
        this.cancelLongPress$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            val = 0;
        });
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (++val > (this.thresholdSeconds * 10)) {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
                val = 0;
                this.onLongPress.emit(true);
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    private cancelLongPress$ = merge(
        fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchend'),
        fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mouseup')
    );
}
```

And use the directive in your HTML template:

```
<button
    longPress
    [thresholdSeconds]="3"
    (onLongPress)="console.log('Long pressed over 3 seconds')"
    (click)="console.log('Clicked')"
>
    Click or long press me
</button>
```